# InvalidValueError: in property destination: not a string; and not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number; and unknown property lat

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> InvalidValueError: in property destination: not a string; and not a
> LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number; and unknown
> property lat

I'm making directions for my application. but when i take **lat** and **lng** values ​​i get error like above. **lat** and **lng** data are Number. here is my code

I got the reference from here [react hook google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66695865/using-react-hooks-and-google-maps-api-how-to-show-one-directions-with-waypoints)

```
const MyDirection = () => {
 const [lat, setLat] = useState("");
 const [lng, setLng] = useState("");
 const [status, setStatus] = useState(null);
 const { id } = useParams();
 const [point, setPoint] = useState(null)
 const prevMarkersRef = useRef([]);

 useEffect(() => {
      getUserById();
 }, []);

 const getUserById = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/datas/${id}`);
      setLat(response.data.lat);
      setLng(response.data.lng);
 };

 useEffect(() => {
      getLocation();
 }, []);

 const getLocation = () => {
      if (!navigator.geolocation) {
           setStatus('Geolocation isn't support your browser');
      } else {
           setStatus('Locating...!!');
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                setStatus(null);
                setPoint({
                     lat: position.coords.latitude,
                     lng: position.coords.longitude
                })
           }, () => {
                setStatus('Can't get location!!');
           });
      }
 }
 
 const dest = {
      lat: lat,
      lng: lng
 };

 // Map options
 const { ref, map, google } = useGoogleMaps(
      "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my_api_key",
      {
           zoom: 6,
           center: point
      }
 );
 useEffect(() => {
      if (map) {
           // ADD MARKER
           const m = addMarker();
           clearMarkers(prevMarkersRef.current); //clear prev markers
           prevMarkersRef.current.push(m);
           map.setCenter(point);
           //Add Directions
           let directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
           let directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
           directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
           calcRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer);
      }
 }, [point]);

 // SIDE FUNCTIONS
 function clearMarkers(markers) {
      for (let m of markers) {
           m.setMap(null);
      }
 }

 function calcRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer) {
      let request = {
           origin: point,
           destination: dest,
           travelMode: "DRIVING"
      };
      directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
           if (status == "OK") {
                directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
           }
      });
 }

 return (
      <div>
           <div ref={ref} style={{ width: 600, height: 800 }} />
      </div>
 );
};

export default MyDirection;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to see what happens.

```
const [lat, setLat] = useState();
const [lng, setLng] = useState();
```

Comment: i got the same error @Poke Player

Comment: const [lat, setLat] = useState(0);
const [lng, setLng] = useState(0);   try this now, from what i've seen it is giving a typing error

Comment: "Directions request returned no results." output in console @Poker Player

Comment: response.data.lat and
response.data.lng

Are they delivering the expected values?

Comment: yeah, when I console the results come out as expected

Comment: replace the ' with ` where you have sentences like ins't, I showed above what it can be.

Comment: done but still error

Comment: 'Can't get location!!' here too, `"Can't get location!!"` or
templateString

Comment: it has nothing to do with it at all

Answer (score 0):

to see what is actually coming from these answers

```
const getUserById = async () => {
          const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/datas/${id}`);
          setLat(response.data.lat);
          setLng(response.data.lng);

          console.log(response.data.lat, typeof(response.data.lat))
          console.log(response.data.lng, typeof(response.data.lng))
     };
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that was it but there was ' in this sentence, `'Geolocation isn't support your browser'`

replace the ' with ` where you have sentences like ins't.

and could be causing isnt conflict as js doesn't know where it started and where it ended the string.

```
const getLocation = () => {
          if (!navigator.geolocation) {
               setStatus(`Geolocation isn't support your browser`); //replace the ' with ` where you have sentences like ins't.
          } else {
               setStatus('Locating...!!');
               navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                    setStatus(null);
                    setPoint({
                         lat: position.coords.latitude,
                         lng: position.coords.longitude
                    })
               }, () => {
                    setStatus(`Can't get location!!`);
               });
          }
     }
```